# Can I use VB.net to build a powerful application which incorporates extensive word processing capabilities?

Tags: vb.net

I am aware of the "reinvent the wheel" objections to such an endeavor.  However, I am interested in the DIY path mainly because I want to figure out for myself how to make it work.  I've read a number of books and I needed to study VB.net for a different reason so I've explored doing this in VB (kill 2 birds with one stone type of reasoning).  However, in *Pro WPF 4.5 in VB* (Apress), there is a passage which states:

"The RichTextBox control also exposes a rich programming model that provides plenty of extensibility points so you can plug in your own logic, which allows you to use the RichTextBox as a building block for your own customized text editor. The one drawback is speed. The WPF RichTextBox, like most of the rich text controls that have preceded it, can be a bit sluggish. ***If you need to hold huge amounts of data, use intricate logic to handle key presses, or add effects such as automatic formatting (for example, Visual Studio’s syntax highlighting or Word’s spelling-checker underlining), the WPF RichTextBox probably won’t provide the performance you need.***" (page 898-899).

No other guidance on this issue appears to be provided in the book.  From what I've found online, it seems MS Office applications are still written in C++ and they obviously don't have these limitations.  Are the performance issues here simply a function of this particular control where I can develop my own WPF controls which don't have these limitations or is this more a problem caused by the overhead of the .Net platform?  I need to study VB.Net either way but I don't want to waste time using this project to learn it if .Net is not a good environment for developing such an application.

Comment: Yes, you should be fine. If you run into performance problems, there will almost certainly be a way around them.

Comment: I think the performance issue warning is due the refresh() method in the richtextbox().  Large objects will slow down a form that is constantly refreshing the object.  When using microsoft word only the current view is refresh while the rest of the document is updated in background mode.

Comment: @jdweng...  I haven't looked at the refresh() method yet but just saw your answer.  However, I think I see what you mean...that all members within the richtextbox() are being iterated over and refreshed each time a change is made rather than refreshing only the element that was changed (i.e. paragraph, run, etc.).  Do you happen to know if the refresh() method is overridable?  Perhaps I can simply extend the richtextbox() and change the logic of that method.

Comment: It isn't great, WPF applications tend to be slow in my experience. Visual Studio never has been the same since the UI was largely rewritten in WPF. It's not a limitation of the VB.NET *language* or the .NET Framework, though.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own RichTextBox that inherits the standard RichTextBox

```
Public Class MyRichTextBox
    Inherits RichTextBox

    Public Shadows Sub Refresh()


    End Sub



End Class
```